# Browser change the domain by ip, Debian, Apache2

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ip, apache2

When I enter in the web browser https://myBuyDomain at the time the web is loaded, it is changed to https://my_Ip_static

- The server works correctly, use ssl but I always accessed through the static ip
- Self-signed CA, Apache2, Debian 9, use google compute engine.
- The only change has been the purchase of the domain, the redirection that I have put is: https://mi_ip_static
- My domain: zzzzzz.page and www.zzzzzz.page
- I do not use any .htaccess

-virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /miPath/web
    ServerName zzzzzz.page
    ServerAlias www.zzzzzz.page

    <Directory /miPath/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    SSLCertificateFile      /otherPath.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /otherPath.key
</VirtualHost>
```

- /etc/host

  `my_ip_static zzzzzz.page www.zzzzzz.page
  127.0.0.1  localhost hostname_machine
  ::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
  ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx aaaaa.aaaa.a.aaaaa.aaaaa old_hostname  # Added by Google
  xxx.xxx.xxx.xx metadata.google.internal  # Added by Google`

Also when I try to install certbot, but it fails for something I do not know where to change:

```
Fetching https://my_ip_static: Invalid host in redirect target "my_ip_static". 
Only domain names are supported, not IP addresses
```

The correct way to do it is using .htaccess to change my_ip_static for the domain? I do not know what I do wrong or what remains to be configured.

Comment: Do  not redirect the URL with the hostname to the URL with the IP address, this makes no sense.

Comment: "https://mi_ip_static" this is an error? I've put it like this to force https traffic. Should I put only the ip?

Comment: As seen in the error message: "Only domain names are supported, not IP addresses", HTTPS works with hostnames in URLs, not with IP address. Do not redirect to an URL with an IP address in it instead of an hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the google domain configuration. I created a redirect to a website. This option is to redirect to an external website but not to your own server.

1 - Remove the website redirection

2 - In the DNS section, create 2 custom resource records

First:

```
     name = @
     Type = A
     TTL = 1h
     Data = static ip of my server
```

Second:

```
     name = www
     Type = A
     TTL = 1h
     Data = static ip of my server
```

That's it, in a few minutes the server is accessible and does not change the domain name by the ip